# Moving arrows and entities through a sentence

Tags: beamer, arrows

Currently, the two arrows are pointing to **jumped** and **over** in the sentence. I was wondering how I can move these two arrows from **The**(at the beginning of the sentence) to **dog**.

EDIT : I am trying to reproduce slides 12-25 from [this](http://www.slideshare.net/ChristopherMoody3/word2vec-lda-and-introducing-a-new-hybrid-algorithm-lda2vec-57135994?qid=d27821c7-7397-41fe-bf35-68e173fa58bb&v=&b=&from_search=1) talk.

My only option is to include images with arrows pointing to different words.

```
\begin{document}
  \frame{
    \frametitle{Learning Algorithm(Contd.)}

    \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig1.PNG}
          \label{fig:Fig1}
    \end{figure}

  }

  \frame{
    \frametitle{Learning Algorithm(Contd.)}

    \begin{figure}
          \includegraphics[width=.9\textwidth]{Fig2.PNG}
          \label{fig:Fig2}
    \end{figure}

  }
  \end{document}
```

[image: Fig1]

[image: Fig2]

Comment: Can you provide a compilable MWE showing what you've done so far?

Comment: Rather than post image files of the output of your code, please post the code itself.

Comment: @Mico, I am not able to position two vertical arrows at the right words and do not want to resort tikz. I thought that was the purpose of my question.

Comment: We won't know *why* you can't move the arrows unless we understand *how* you're placing the arrows at present. For that, we need to see the code, not an image file. Please note that I haven't claimed you should "resort [to] tikz".

Comment: From your code I can conclude that you use `beamer` as document class and that you so far use images (drawn in unknown program), which you include in frame as image. What is your question actually? How to make animation in which you  in desired sequence uncover/hide your images? Or how to draw new images? Or how to draw/wrote this images with LaTeX?

Comment: @Zarko As the example is missing `\documentclass{beamer}` we can't even conclude that ...

Comment: If you do not know how to insert the arrows with latex, you could at least provide a MWE that prints the text about the fox and the dog.

Comment: Sorry about the unwarranted confusion. I have edited my question to show the desired output. I am not able to churn up an MWE, but it would be great if there are some pointers towards this.

Comment: @envy_intelligence - It would be really, really useful to know how you create `Fig1.PNG` and `Fig2.PNG`.

Comment: Oh that was using keynote. I just wrote the sentence in a frame -- took the snapshot and appended the arrows in KeyNote. I was just wondering if there is a more sophisticated way of going about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a custom `array` environment to stack the word/arrow/explanation triplets. Observe the use of the `\color` macro to set colors.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for "\mathclap" macro
\newcommand\stacktab[2]{%
    $\begin{array}[t]{@{}c@{}}
     \text{#1} \\ \uparrow \\ \mathclap{#2} \end{array}$}
\newcommand\uIN{\upsilon^{}_{\!IN}}
\newcommand\uOUT{\upsilon^{}_{\!OUT}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
The quick brown fox \stacktab{jumped}{\uOUT} 
\stacktab{\color{blue}over}{\uIN} the lazy dog.

\bigskip
\stacktab{\color{magenta}The}{\uOUT} quick brown fox jumped 
\stacktab{\color{red}over}{\uIN} the lazy dog.

\bigskip
The quick brown fox jumped over the \stacktab{lazy}{\uIN} 
\stacktab{\color{purple}dog}{\ \uOUT}. % shift "\UOUT" slightly to the right

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```